# How can I make password SSH more secure?

Tags: windows, ssh, security, passwords, openssh

I need to log into a machine using a password. (This machine is provisioned automatically for me and others, and keys aren't provided, only individual passwords)

At first I used openssh from Windows Terminal, with all config for this machine in `~/.ssh/config`, but I still needed to introduce the password manually which I don't want to keep doing.

I'm currently using a powershell script that creates a SecureString that holds the password in some text file, and then reads the encrypted password to feed it to a plink oneliner like `plink [...] -pw $PASS`. Is there any other application that allows this in a more secure way?

Clarifying further:

1. I don't have permission to create SSH key pairs. Writing passwords directly into the terminal is neither safe nor convenient
2. I can't use WSL or unix tools. Just powershell or binaries like plink.exe

Comment: Based on `SecureString`, it looks like you are writing a code.  So what is your programming language?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you want to make "more secure"? What do you mean with "keys aren't provided, only individual passwords"? The SSH key pair is normally created *by yourself* on the (every) client/local machine, and you have to add your *public* key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the serve/remote machine(s). So use password-based authentication for doing this once and then switch to key-based authentication .

Comment: If you use PowerShell, why don't you use some .NET SSH implementation? E.g. SSH.NET?